# Is there a bug in visionOS TabBar Preview?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, visionos

Playing around with `visionOS` I'm rewriting SwiftUI tutorials to launch on Xcode visionOS simulator, everything's working fine so far, but adding any `TabView` makes preview crash (even when it's working on running). Here's my code.

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    Text("Tab 1")
        .tabItem {
            Label("Featured", systemImage: "star")
        }
        .tag(Tab.featured)

    Text("Tab 2")
        .tabItem {
            Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet")
        }
        .tag(Tab.list)
 }
```

Anything I might be missing?

Comment: See [Tab views](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-views#Platform-considerations): *Not supported in iOS, iPadOS, tvOS, or visionOS.*

Comment: Thank you @KevinM.Mansour. Interesting, however this doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview seems to suggest that it is supported, and it's actually working on the simulator.

Comment: Didn't you say it's not working on the simulator, what's your problem *exactly*? not sure but I guess visionOS is super new, even the link you mentioned says *beta* which means don't expect it to be working 99% of all time, and even the difference between both links means that the documentation isn't up to date *yet* so we may even expect changes later. This is basically the answer currently.

Comment: Also: [see this article](https://zoewave.medium.com/developing-for-apple-visionos-9e5a78df3867) which is also under development but it suggests that TabView is working on visionOS, they had this simple code: `TabView { 
DogsTab() .tabItem { Label("Dogs", systemImage: "pawprint") }
CatsTab() .tabItem { Label("Cats", image: "cat") }
BirdsTab() .tabItem { Label("Birds", systemImage: "bird") } }` If this works I'd guess the issue is from someplace else in your code.

Comment: Yep, it works on simulator but crashes on xcode preview, I presume it might be a bug in the xcode 15 beta, just wanted to double check if someone already faced the issue. Thank you @KevinM.Mansour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug in visionOS. Put `TabView` inside `NavigationSplitView`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            TabView {
                Text("Tab One")
                    .tabItem { Label("Featured", systemImage: "star") }
                    .onAppear { text = "Tab One's Items" }
                Text("Tab Two")
                    .tabItem { Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet") }
                    .onAppear { text = "Items of Tab Two" }
            }.tabViewStyle(.page)
            List {
                Text(text)
                    .onChange(of: text) { _, newValue in
                        text = newValue
                    }
            }
        } detail: {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AndyJazz, this fixes the preview error indeed. Still I'd rather keeping the NavigationViews individually inside the child views (and the fact that doing it so fails on preview but works in simulator does look like a bug), but at least your approach does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Following @AndyJazz answer, I ended up wrapping my `TabView` inside a `ZStack` (instead of `NavigationSplitView`). This way I can set different navigation strategies for each children in the `TabView` (i.e. I have one `NavigationView` and one `NavigationStack`).

Answer (score 0):

[TabViews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) should work fine in the Xcode preview.

You do not need to add a NavigationStack for TabView to work. Whatever you put before the `.tabView` modifier will appear in the main screen when that tab is selected.

Adding a NavigationStack adds an extra column to the main view in VisionOS that is unnecessary.

[image]